# Django App Labels and User Rights

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I have an App with a few models. All of the Models have app_label in META set.

Now i want to give certain users certain rights from these models. No Custom Rights, just plain add/change/delete rights that com from Django. But, if the App has the app_label the admin does not show these.

As the Rights one can give to a user are named like the app (even if app_label is set) i guess its because django just cant find the Models? ... their app label obviously  changed ...

What am i missing here (if something at all) and how could i come around this?

i'm using django 1.3

Comment: "I have an App with a few models. All of the Models have app_label in META set." -> why ?

Comment: Because the name i chose in the first place ist bad. Or better, we want it to be more understandable to the Editors.

Comment: That's [not what app_label is for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label), are you sure this is not the source of your issues ? You could set this verbose names in the templates or a translation probably.

Comment: The Goal is to alter the title of the Box's (whoich then hold the apps models) that make up the apps in the admin.

Answer (score 1):

You should not change app_label unless [you have a good reason](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label).

Unfortunnately, there is no supported way to change the name of the app that will show in the admin.

First, i checked the admin code and noticed that it relies on the [title() string method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

```
class AdminSite(object):
    # snip ....

    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        # snip .....
                        app_dict[app_label] = {
                            'name': app_label.title(),
                            'app_url': reverse('admin:app_list', kwargs={'app_label': app_label}, current_app=self.name),
                            'has_module_perms': has_module_perms,
                            'models': [model_dict],
                        }
```

So a solution would be to set app_label to a string that has an overloaded title method, for example, to use such a translation:

```
msgid "testapp"
msgstr "My test application"
```

You can have a hack like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class TitleHack(str):
    def title(self):
        return _(self)

class Student(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = TitleHack(__package__)
```

Now, that's pretty nasty and you should fully understand this code before you use it. Hopefully it's not rocket science but still totally unsupported.

The problem that, for some obscure reason, the admin does **not** always rely on title(), it's actually pretty inconsistent. The best you can do is [override the admin template per app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and hardcode you app name in there.

Else, you'd have to fix the name in other parts of the admin in python, and that's pretty boilerplaty:

```
class HackedAppLabelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
        """ take care of app_label for add and change view """
        context['app_label'] = self.model._meta.app_label.title()
        return super(HackedAppLabelAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, add, change, form_url, obj)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        """ take care of the changelist view """
        extra_context = extra_context or {} 
        extra_context['app_label'] = self.model._meta.app_label.title()
        return super(HackedAppLabelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)

admin.site.register(Student, HackedAppLabelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, will try that. I thought of app_label as the Label/Title for the App ... ^^ not as the app's module name.